# Configure poetry to create x86 environment

Tags: python, rosetta-2

## TLDR

How can I configure `poetry` to use/create an `x86` environment?

## Details

My python project has a dependency that is not available for apple silicon (I use a Macbook Pro M2). A plain `pip install` will run into an error:

```bash
installing pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2): Failed
RuntimeError
Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2)
```

### What works

Using `conda` to handle the virtual environment, I can enforce the `x86` version of the dependencies like so:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n my-intel-env python=3.11 -y
conda activate my-intel-env
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64
conda deactivate
conda activate my-intel-env
pip install "poetry==1.5.1"
poetry install --with dev
```

```bash
...
  • Installing pymiscutils (0.3.14)
  • Installing pyqt5 (5.15.9)
  • Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
...
```

### What doesn't

However, I'd like to ditch `conda` and use `poetry` exclusively, i.e., *also for creating the venv*. For this, I have a `poetry.toml` file in the project root:

```
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

When running `poetry install` while not having a venv activated, this will create a `.venv` folder inside the project root, and install all dependencies into it, which is what I want. However, it fails in the same way as described at the top.

**How can I configure `poetry` to use `x86`, similarly to how I did it for `conda`?**

Comment: The question as written ie use x86 on Apple is a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The alternative is to get pyqt5 comiled as arm - which would also be a good question for SO.